# Простенький учебник по настройке Git

Tags: git, книги

Посоветуйте учебник по Git для начинающих (а лучше даже для чайников). В интернете искал, но что-то не так, что-то всё не устраивает...

Comment: В интернете полно книг и обсуждений на эту тему. Задавайте вопросы, на которые можно чётко отвечать, а не те, которые порождают дискуссии.

Comment: Вопрос задавал, когда ещё этот сайт был хешкодом)))

Comment: Вопрос был в очереди проверок. Как-то не обратил внимания на дату )

Answer (score 7):

Возможно, это подойдет: [Завершён перевод книги «Pro Git»](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150673/)

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится вот этот: [Git How To](http://githowto.com/ru), а вообще главное ручками попробовать. Для базовой работы его хватает.  Для чего-то серьезнее приходится лезть [в доки](http://git-scm.com/docs).

Comment: немного помогло... но в командной строке не очень... может есть "в виде окошек"?

Comment: @sitev_ru, из гуевых есть tortouise git и atlassian sourcetree, но все они используют обычные консольные команды внутри. Увы, работать с консолью надо, без этого при любой непонятной ситуации будут проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Вот мой вольный перевод книги Git: Version control for everyone:

[Git: система управления версиями для всех. Меньше теории, больше практики](http://devtype.blogspot.com/2013/10/Git-sistema-upravlenija-versijami-dlja-vseh-Menshe-teorii-bolshe-praktiki.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://git-scm.com/book/ru